# QGIS Cloud and relations

Tags: qgis, qgis-cloud, relation

Does publishing to QGIS cloud preserve the established relations (1 to many relation) between layers? On the web map, can you see the embedded form of the Parent layer in the Child layer, for example?

Answer (score 1):

I understand that the data are stored in PostGres/PostGIS in QGIS Cloud, so I doubt table relationships created in QGIS are somehow uploaded.
If you create a join between a Spatial Layer and an external data source; after the join the data that you see in the table will be loaded.

In this example I have added data from an excel file containing the section numbers into a point Layer that did not have the data.

[image]

The picture below shows that the join has been preserved on QGIS Cloud.

[image]

https://qgiscloud.com/